# Calling function outside vue component

Tags: laravel, vuejs2, vue.js

Currently Im working with Laravel and Vue, and now I want to use a 3rd party javascript library for tag-input fields. https://github.com/xoxco/jQuery-Tags-Input

I have to initialize the field in javascript by calling:

```
 $('#tags').tagsInput();
```

However the tag-input field is inside of my vue component. I have tried calling this line from vue but that is not working.

Now I want to know which options do I have? Can I declare a function on my javascript and call that from within the Vue component? Can I pass the entire thing as a variable? Or are there other solutions to this case?

Someone who has experience with this and perhaps knows the right steps I have to take? Thanks in advance.

Comment: When are you making this call?  You can't use the normal `document.ready` handler.  Ideally, this would be placed in the [mounted](https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#mounted) handler for the component that is generating the element with the id "tags".

Comment: try window.$('#tags').tagsInput() inside your ready function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get vue component DOM element by [this.$el](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-el). So you can do the following:

```
$(this.$el.querySelector('#tags')).tagsInput();
```

But remember this is valid as long as your component is not a [Fragment Instance](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Named-Slots) i.e. it has a single root HTML tag

Comment: I get tagsInput(); is not a function. I think it happens because I have no access to the javascript from within vue?

Comment: @Don `querySelector` returns an `HTMLElement`, wrap it with jquery: `$(...)`